# Save only specific output to log file

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, unison

I'm using `unison` to synchronise data to a server, and I've recently created a cronjob for this. The cronjob is running at startup and saves the output to a log file. (additional info below).

The problem I'm having is that unison has quite a lot of output, and I'd like to only save the summary to the log file. Is there a way to do that? I haven't found a way to make unison less verbose, so I thought maybe the output can be filtered somehow - I just wouldn't know how.

Thanks!

Additional info:

Right now, the log file ends up looking like this:

```
Contacting server...
Connected [//theserver//share/HDA_DATA/elrudi -> //thelaptop//home/elrudi]
Looking for changes
\ syncAll/Code/Aptana/T...avascript library code assist.txt

\ syncAll/Code/develope...nk/20070607 contacten (INDEX).xls

\ syncAll/Code/sourcefi...okexport/photos/10152112061815397

| syncAll/Code/Python/d...rawable-hdpi/ic_action_search.png

(... many many lines ...)

| syncAll/Work/2008_10 ...profile/StandardLastprofil_H0.xls

| syncAll/Work/2008_10 ...n/Load Profiles/Lastprofil_H0.xls

Waiting for changes from server
Reconciling changes
changed  ---->            syncAll/scriptfile1.sh 
Propagating updates
UNISON 2.40.102 started propagating changes at 12:07:31.55 on 07 Oct 2015
[BGN] Updating file syncAll/scriptfile1.sh from /home/elrudi to //theserver//share/HDA_DATA/elrudi
100%  00:00 ETA

[END] Updating file syncAll/scriptfile1.sh
100%  00:00 ETA

UNISON 2.40.102 finished propagating changes at 12:07:31.61 on 07 Oct 2015
100%  00:00 ETA

Saving synchronizer state
Synchronization complete at 12:07:36  (1 item transferred, 0 skipped, 0 failed)
```

I'd want to ditch the lines starting with `|`, `/`, `-`, or `\` (the spinning bar indicating a process is not finished yet).

More additional info:
`crontab -e` shows

```
@reboot /home/elrudi/sync.sh -batch 60 >> /home/elrudi/.cronjobs.log 2>&1
```

The `sync.sh` script checks whether the server is locally reachable or remotely, and runs the appropriate `unison` command. The `-batch` parameter is added to make `unison` run without user input, and the `60` is a waiting time (to make sure `unison` does not run before a connection is available).

Comment: Don't immediately redirect do the log file, but pipe through `sed` or `grep` first to filter the output.

Comment: have you tried the `-terse` option to unison? (never tried it --- but the manual says "-terse: suppress status messages")

Comment: Hmmm `-terse` is not bad either. It's a bit too quiet for my taste, but it'd have done the job too, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `unison` in your `sync.sh` script call it as follows:

```
unison ... 2>&1 | grep -vE '^[\|/-]|^$'
```

This will remove (`-v`) all line that match the regual expression: All line beginning with one of those characters: `\|/-`, or complete empty lines (`^$`).

---

**Edit**: If you want the cronjob to be filtered, use:

```
@reboot /path/to/sync.sh -batch 60 2>&1 | grep -vE '^[\|/-]|^$' >> /path/to/logfile
```

Comment: Nice, I was trying to figure out a way with `sed`, which I'm quite new to, and was tying my brain in knots about escaping special characters. Good old `grep` can save a lot of headaches from over complicating things!

Comment: @kos True, but stderr of `unison` itself would then not be filtered with `grep`. If that is desired: ok. I don't know `unison`, but some tools send teihr process animation via stderr.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense :) As it has come up: is there a way to output the errors, if any occur, to a separate log file?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm so silly, for some reason I thought `stderr` redirection came before `stdout` redirection in OP's command. Indeed that's correct, removed my comments

Comment: Ah and, it is not possible to do the `grep` filtering at the cronjob? I ask as the script is also used to perform a manual sync, during which all output is appreciated. If it is indeed not possible I guess I could add a parameter to the script to toggle filtering, but I'd prefer to have it at the cronjob level, if that makes sense

Comment: @ElRudi see my edit